# Java Ethernet traffic generator - read Ethernet load

Tags: java, tcp, generator, ethernet, sniffer

I am developing a Java application to read/write PLC values trough Modbus TCP, I am using modbus4j.
In the same application I want to generate Ethernet TCP traffic, and read the Ethernet load.

Do you know some lava library to do this?

Best regards.

Comment: Does it have to be Java? For instance you could use something like WireShark to monitor the TCP traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but yes, I need some Java library because I am developing a Java application with Java libraries. (modbus4j).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to do this using naitive libraries.  I know Java has some limitations as to what it can/cannot do.  For instance, there is no naitive "ping" in Java.

Comment: I found the next java library: netutils, http://code.google.com/p/netutils/       But When I try to use the ping function I have the next error:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:edu.huji.cs.netutils.capture.impl.JPCapWraper.get_all_devices(Z)Ljava/lang/String;                   Something know this library? And How Can I solve this error?